# Ruby: Outputting Sequel model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql-9.2, sequel

I don't think this is possible using just Sequel models, but what I would like to do is have my parent model (**Author**) output its child model (**Book**) when I do something like `Author.to_json`.  Here is my code:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'json'

db = Sequel.connect('postgres://localhost/testing');

class Sequel::Model
  self.plugin :json_serializer
end

class Author < Sequel::Model(:author)
  one_to_many :book, key: :author_id, primary_key: :id

  def get_author
    Author.each do |e|
      books = Array.new
      e.book.each do |f|
        books.push(f.values)
      end
      e.values[:books] = books
      puts JSON.pretty_generate(e.values)
    end
  end
end

class Book < Sequel::Model(:book)
end

author = Author.new
author.get_author
```

My output looks something like this:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jack Johnson",
  "books": [{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Songs with Chords",
    "genre": "Learning",
    "author_id": 1
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Mulder",
  "books": [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "UFOs",
    "genre": "Mystery",
    "author_id": 2
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Unexplained Paranorma",
    "genre": "Suspense",
    "author_id": 2
  }]
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Michael Crichton",
  "books": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jurassic Park",
    "genre": "Incredible",
    "author_id": 3
  }]
}]
```

That's exactly how I want my output to look, but the way I'm going about it is questionable.  Ideally, if there's some function already on the Author model that allows me to do this, that'd be awesome... as I don't want to have to implement a **get_model** function for all of my models that have different associations.  Also, I was hoping [NestedAttributes](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/NestedAttributes.html) could lend a hand here, but it doesn't look like it.

I'm very new to Ruby and Sequel, so I'd like to know if there's a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, so that won't work. Typically to do what you want, define a `to_json` for your class, and inside that method you can gather everything you want to return, then create a hash and do a `to_json` on it. Also, don't use pretty JSON output for production output; It's bloated and slows both your server, the transmission of the blob, and the parser on the other end.

Comment: Yeah, the JSON was there more as a proof of concept, rather than exactness, but I'll add in the brackets to ensure that... this obviously isn't official code, and I was more or less playing around with it to get an idea across, but from what you said, it sounds like my answer is "No, you have to create a method similar to what you're currently doing."

Comment: Also, `Author.to_json` wouldn't be appropriate. A class method won't give you the granularity you want unless you intend to return everything about all objects of that class. Instead, `foo = Author.new` followed by doing something with that instance, then `foo.to_json` would make more sense. Then it'd return only information specific to that particular instance of Author. Sequel's JSON serializer is great, but it's generic. Your use is specialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequel's `json_serializer` plugin already has support for associations via the `:include` option.  Also, you need to fix your association.  Something like this should work:

```
Author.one_to_many :books
Author.order(:id).to_json(:include=>:books)
```

Comment: That's awesome... only problem is that it's one giant string, but I can work with it, as I may've seen some sort of fix for that somewhere.  Thanks so much!  Also, why is my association wrong?

Comment: What is one giant string? The JSON output? If so that's good. It's efficient that way, which parsers like. Humans don't usually need to see that output, and, if they do, a browser with a JSON plugin should render it nicely indented and structured.

Comment: Your association uses :book and not :books, and one_to_many associations should use the plural form.  The :key and :primary_key options you used are the same as the default values, so they are not necessary.