# Ruby: Outputting Sequel schema with associations

Tags: ruby, postgresql-9.2, sequel

Similar to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369336/ruby-outputting-sequel-model-associations), but in this case, I want to get the schema of Authors with its association (Books).  Here's what my code looks like:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'json'

db = Sequel.connect('postgres://localhost/testing');

class Sequel::Model
  self.plugin :json_serializer
end

class Author < Sequel::Model(:author)
  one_to_many :books
end

class Book < Sequel::Model(:book)
end
```

But when I do `Author.db_schema`, I'm only given the Author class's information... not the associations that it contains.

```
{
  :id=>{
    :oid=>23,
    :db_type=>"integer",
    :default=>"nextval('author_id_seq'::regclass)",
    :allow_null=>false,
    :primary_key=>true,
    :type=>:integer,
    :ruby_default=>nil
  },
  :name=>{
    :oid=>1043,
    :db_type=>"character varying",
    :default=>nil,
    :allow_null=>true,
    :primary_key=>false,
    :type=>:string,
    :ruby_default=>nil
  }
}
```

Is it possible to show that there's at least some sort of association with Book, and if possible, maybe include that information into the Author schema?  Something along the lines of [this](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/xml_schema_generation.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to call `Author.all_association_reflections` to get metadata on associations (`db_schema` just gives column schema metadata).  See http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/reflection_rdoc.html for details on Sequel's reflection methods.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I can definitely work with that.  Thanks!